# what is the difference beetwen dw and db with dup in assembly

Tags: assembly, binary, masm

I want to know what is the difference between this code and this code in assembly language:

```
a db 2 dup (1fh)
b dw 1fh,1fh
```

and I think that the second code is better and I don't know why they make number first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd line is equivalent to `db 1fh, 0, 1fh, 0`, because each arg to DW is a word-sized integer.  (And x86 is little-endian)

The 1st line is equivalent to `db 1fh, 1fh`.

To do that with DW, use `dw 1f1fh`.  For a very short constant, that's maybe clearer.  For anything more than 2 repeats of 2 bytes, using the `dup` syntax is probably clearer for other humans to see that it's the same thing multiple times, without having to look carefully to check for differences.

---

If you're using an assembler which implicitly associates a size with a symbol, it matters whether you use `dw` or `db`, so if you want the symbol to be declared as a `byte` "variable", you need `a db 1fh,1fh` or `a db 2 dup (1fh)`.

---

Think of `dup` as an operator where the left side is the count and the right side is the thing being repeated.  Like Python's `'abc' * 3` being equivalent to `"abcabcabc"`, or Perl's `'abc' x 4`, except with the order of the operands reversed.

IDK why MASM is designed this way.

NASM syntax is `times 2  db 0x1f`.  The `times` repeats a whole pseudo-instruction, or a whole instruction like `times 3 imul eax, ecx`.